# VideoView change (reduce) layout_height in emulator

Tags: android, url, size, android-videoview

[this image show the xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1jqP.png)

[this image show the probleme in android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylyo1.png)

> the java code is very simple (read video from url and display it in a videoview)

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot UI view is in Nexus 4(768*1280) and your app running device is Nexus 5(1080*1920).

Comment: i change running device to Nexus4, but always same problem